# Remove duplicate batches of data

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Due to a bug in my application a table that was built to carry daily records of each delivery period, was populated many times.

Lets say I have a delivery from 1st of June to 5 of June. My table should be populated with 5 records, one for each day. Now, I have havoc because I have many "batches" of the same content.

The table layout is as:

```
dummy_id       -- identity column
delivery_id    -- id of the delivery
on_date        -- the day
charge         -- the daily cost
```

Is there an elegant way to keep only the first batch of records and delete the batches that were inserted by mistake for all the deliveries?

Comment: Do you know the ID of the batch you want to keep? You could just delete all but that ID

Comment: so there's multiple records for each day, where there should only be one?

Comment: do you have any date and time field that records when record was inserted on a day?

Comment: @MarcB I think thats what hes saying. Basically delete all the duplicates

Comment: Yes I want to delete the duplicates and keep the first "batches" of each delivery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To delete all dupes for `delivery_id, on_date, charge` keeping the one with the lowest `dummy_id`

```
;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY delivery_id,
                                                on_date,
                                                charge
                                       ORDER BY dummy_id) RN
         FROM   YourTable)
DELETE FROM cte
WHERE  RN > 1
```

Comment: @user597243 semicolons are required to terminate preceding statements to common table expression declarations. The addition of the semi colon in my answer is just a pre-emptive measure in case you paste it into the middle of a non semi colon terminated set of statements.

Comment: Thanx! I will create a test envioroment to check it and I will get back! Seems sci-fi :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

This is to know which rows you will delete:

```
SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLE WHERE DUMMY_ID NOT IN (
   SELECT MIN(DUMMY_ID) FROM YOUR_TABLE GROUP BY DELIVERY_ID)
```

This will delete these rows:

```
DELETE FROM YOUR_TABLE WHERE DUMMY_ID NOT IN (
   SELECT MIN(DUMMY_ID) FROM YOUR_TABLE GROUP BY DELIVERY_ID)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE dummy_id NOT IN (SELECT MIN(dummy_id) FROM table GROUP BY on_date)
```